# How do I extract elements of a martix from a list in r?

Tags: r, list, matrix, extract

I have a list composed by a vector and a matrix. I want to extract the element (3,2) of the matrix from the list. How do I do that?

```
mymatr <- matrix(1:10 , nrow = 5) 
myvecto <- 1:5
mylist <- list(myvecto, mymatr)
```

Comment: If the matrix is always second in the list, you would do `mylist[[2]][3,2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code:

```
 > mylist[[2]][3,2]
```

Output:

```
8
```